# x64 assembly system calls to interrupts

Tags: assembly

Is 8 bit and 16 bit assembly OS independent and how can I write OS independent x64 bit assembly?

Specifically I want skip OS based system calls and use interrupts like int21h (or whatever the special stunt for using interrupts on x64 assembly) and such on x64. In this example is on how to write manual system calls but I don't get it. Is 39h interrupt?

Code:

```
Manual_WPM proc

mov r10, rcx
mov eax, 39h   ; Syscall Index for WPM (This one is for Win8.1)
syscall
ret

Manual_WPM endp 

end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: TL:DR: there is no cross-OS portable ABI for making anything like system calls, and definitely nothing that *bypasses* the OS.  The whole point of process isolation is to protect processes from each other, so of course the OS must stop them doing anything other than manipulating registers + memory *directly*, without going through the OS.

Answer (score 3):

`int 21h` is completely OS-dependent.  It generates a "software interrupt" which is essentially a trap to the OS, for the OS's handler for handler number 21 (hex).  For DOS, handler 0x21 is the Function Dispatcher, which interprets register AH for the caller to specify which function to dispatch to.

My guess is that this would do a completely different thing on a different OS such as Linux, but maybe Linux preserved some DOS conventions.

These *are* OS-based system calls, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Trying to access hardware by sidestepping the OS is very unlikely to be fruitful, for example.

Comment: The question changed substantially after I posted this answer, so it may now appear non-sequitur.

Comment: "My guess is that this would do a completely different thing on a different OS such as Linux": 32-bit Linux does use `int 0x80` for the same reason.

Comment: what I'm tryin to do is write an assembly code that can run on many processors for example if I write assembly code for intel wolfdale then I want it to run on all wolfdale irrespective if the os on top. is that possible?

Comment: Sorry but that's way too broad a question for StackOverflow.  Perhaps you'll get some pointers in comments, but in general it takes a lot of design work and experience to write code that's OS-independent unless you stick to languages and libraries that are ported to lots of platforms.  For assembly code, you can do it as long as you stay away from OS calls, for example, a very fast array algorithm or some other compute-bound problem.  If it involves I/O, your chances are not good.

Comment: @BefikerBiresaw That's not possible in general.  While I can imagine some contortions that could bring you close to this goal, it's not really something that is a good idea to do.  Just provide binaries for each operating system with the system call code swapped as needed.

Comment: The BIOS interrupts like `int 10h` / ah=whatever would be a better example than DOS `int 21h`.  But of course they're still totally OS-dependent.  @BefikerBiresaw: Only things like DOS (not a multi-tasking OS; every process runs with kernel privileges) allow software to access hardware through the BIOS interface instead of only through the OS.  Any "real" OS will install its own IDT (interrupt descriptor table), and the handler for `10h` will treat it as an error / segmentation fault, like Linux, OS X, and Windows do.

Comment: You can write OS-independent code as long as you don't need anything from OS. Considering the modern OS provide you with memory and any I/O and HW access, you are limited to pure algorithm code operating on limited amount of memory (probably using mostly stack area), and without any means to get input or provide output. If you are writing larger app in asm (doesn't make sense, but IF you do), it still makes sense to design code in a way where OS interaction is wrapped in few functions providing support for other "clean algorithm" ones, so you need to port only small part of source to other OS.

Comment: @BefikerBiresaw The code will be of course CPU dependent, as it's raw machine code, so only the target CPU will be able to execute it. (and for example x86 CPUs have now several different operating modes, 16b, 32 and 64b, each of them being basically different CPU (but with major overlaps in opcodes, instructions and behaviour, so it feels like the same thing, but as a target for producing machine code you can think about those as different machines).